# Objective C implementation with C++ Api

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, header-files

Lets I have C++ header such as:

```
    class Color 
{
public:
    Boolean OnInitDialog();
 };
```

Could I do the implementation in ObjectiveC with something like:

```
-(BOOL) OnInitDialog
{
...
return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create an Objective-C class and then write a c++ wrapper for it. Something along the lines of

color.h

```
@interface Color : NSObject
{
    ...
}
- (BOOL) onInitDialog;
@end
```

color.m

```
#import "color.h"

@implementation Color
- (BOOL) onInitDialog
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

colorwrapper.h

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
@class Color;
#else
struct Color;
#endif

class ColorWrapper
{
    Color *color;
public:
    Boolean OnInitDialog();
};
```

colorwrapper.mm

```
#include "ColorWrapper.h"

Boolean ColorWrapper::OnInitDialog()
{
    return [color onInitDialog];
}
```

Of course this is not complete code and probably is not completely right... but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

You can, however utilize C++ code in your implementation just by naming the file `.mm` instead of `.m`.

Curious, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I'm modifying  an existing C++ implementation and I also wanted to make the function ObjC styled, a language I'm more familiar with.

Comment: gotcha.  Without going through a "wrapper" like filipe mentioned, you're stuck in C++-land for now :)

Answer (score 0):

if your header is C++, your implementation should be C++. If your header is Objective C, your implementation should be Objective C.

you could use C++ and Obj-C together. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html